# How to make format filter for two way binding using AngularJS

Tags: json, wcf, rest, angularjs, data-binding

On the page I have `<input type="text" />` to which user will enter date in format `31/12/2013`. This input field should be binded to `$scope.startDate` field. But on `$scope.startDate` I have to store date in following format `"/Date(1385063675188)/"` (WCF REST service date format).

**Question:** How to make two way binding between html input and AngularJS model where date on both will be in different format (`dd/MM/yyyy` and `"/Date(1385063675188)/"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scope.$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24watch)

```
scope.$watch("model", function (newValue) {
    scope.formattedModel = convertToWcfFormat(newValue);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a directive for this. Like so:

```
directives.directive('dateConverter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(date) {
          // Do to model conversion
        });

        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(date) {
          // Do to view conversion, possibly using $filter('date')
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```